# Chart C# two tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, charts, datatable

I have two tables

**Medical_Expense**

```
medicalexp_id (pk) ,                         
medical_setupid(fk) ,                       
medicalexp_amount ,
medicalexp_Date
```

**Medical_Exp_Setup**

```
medical_setupid(pk),
medicalexpense_type
```

---

Now here i want to bind a Asp.net Chart with two tables.
**x** value will be medicalexpense_type and **Y** value will be medicalexp_amount ,so any one can tell me how can i write sql query to bind these two tables with  Asp.net chart control.

Comment: Please write a better title based your specific problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/writing-a-good-title

Comment: Sure. Here is sql query: `select medicalexpense_type as X, medicalexp_amount as Y from Medical_Exp_Setup as stp join Medical_Expense as exp on stp.medical_setupid=exp.medical_setupid`

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [**Microsoft Tutorial**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489231(v=vs.140).aspx) (haven't tested it) you can try the following query into the SQL statement field in the Properties window of the Chart control (Data category)

```
select ms.medicalexpense_type, me.medicalexp_amount 
  from Medical_Expense as me
  inner join Medical_Exp_Setup as ms on me.medical_setupid = ms.medical_setupid
```

When the SQL data source is now bound to the Chart control with the data columns specified in the query, you can then bind data to the X and Y values in the chart:

1. Open the Series Collection Editor for the Chart control.
2. In the **Properties** window for the default series, in the **Data Source**
   category, click the **XValueMember** property, then click the drop-down
   arrow, and then select **medicalexpense_type**. The **XValueMember** drop-down list displays all the columns returned by the data source that is bound to the Chart control.
3. Click the **YValueMembers** property, then click the drop-down arrow,
   and then select **medicalexp_amount**. The X value of the default series is now
   bound to the **medicalexpense_type** column, and the first Y value of the default
   series is now bound to the **medicalexp_amount** column
4. In the Series Collection Editor, click Add, and then do the same to
   the new series with the following values:

---

```
Property       Value
XValueMember   medicalexpense_type
YValueMembers  medicalexp_amount
```

5. Click OK.

.

Comment: Thanks Chirdam and Reniuz !